# How can I change from CKEditor's inline editor to the balloon editor?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Very much a junior dev playing around so hope this makes sense!

I've been using the Inline editor from CK editor for my project, however I'm having an issue upon making the area scroll where the toolbar moves out of the box when I scroll down ([video here](https://monosnap.com/file/QRsjqZYZ7SHjkVH9CBYKz549KDGyw2)). I've tried to find a way to fix this but not having much luck.

I did see that CK editor has a balloon editor instead and with that the toolbar only pops up when text is selected. I thought that might resolve for my use case.

I uninstalled the CK editor and inline editor, made sure they were no longer in my dependencies and then installed again using:
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon
npm install @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react

However it won't work - the page is blank. In the console I get an error:

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') at to.createEditor (ckeditor.js:6:28711) at Hr.eval [as _creator] (ckeditor.js:6:28372) at eval (ckeditor.js:6:20766) at async to._initializeEditor (ckeditor.js:6:28514) at async to.componentDidMount (ckeditor.js:6:27896)`

When I then uninstall the balloon editor and reinstall the inline one, that version works fine again. I did see a warning in the CK editor files about having two plugins... is there a way to make this work?

The code in my component to load the inline editor looks like this

```
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'
import InlineEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline'

 const handleBodyChange = (e, editor) => {
    setBody(editor.getData())
    setShowBodyButtons(true)
    setShowTitleSaved(false)
    setShowBodySaved(false)
  }

<CKEditor
  editor={InlineEditor}
  data={singleRequest?.body || 'Click to add text'}
  onChange={handleBodyChange}
/>
```

I'm using Reactjs, redux, webpack... not sure what else would be relevant but can expand if needed.